# Uninstall drivers on an orphaned hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, transfer

Basically, I need a hard drive (originally from a computer I no longer have) to work on new machine.

What I need from the drive is the configuration of the software installed, *not the data*.

It has Windows 7 installed but with the drivers for the old machine's hardware. And booting into the drive in a new machine causes an expected BSOD and restart cycle as the hardware has dramatically changed.

**How do I uninstall the old drivers from that hard drive?** Or better: what's the best way to transfer a drive to a new machine that is not similar to the old one?

*Already tried: System Repair via repair disk (says it could not repair), and Safe Mode (it just restarts anyway).*

Comment: You may want to check the SATA mode (IDE/AHCI). That's probably the most common cause of failure to boot on drive migration...

Comment: if it was a running system, you'd want to run sysprep - but thats not an option in this case. Could you try imaging the disk (to be safe), and installing over without reformatting the disk? It used to work with XP, but not sure about 7